# Is it possible to define recursive DataType in PySpark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a schema like this example:

```py
friendSchema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("friends",**friendSchema**,True)
```

I understand the data must be normalized but I was wondering if Spark has the functionality to create a schema like the above. If so, how can one do it? Is it doable using *UDT*?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible. What you're looking to do is called a *nested struct*. A `StructType` schema can itself include `StructType` fields, which will do what you want. So for example:

```
def test_build_nested_schema(self):
    internal_struct = StructType([(StructField("friend_struct", StringType()))])
    friend_schema = StructType([
        StructField("firstname", StringType(), True),
        StructField("middlename", StringType(), True),
        StructField("friends", internal_struct, True)])
    empty_df = self.spark.createDataFrame([], schema=friend_schema)
    empty_df.printSchema()
```

Which will output:

```
root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- friends: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- friend_struct: string (nullable = true)
```

[Documentation link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html).

Comment: Friends schema is string though not another struct!

Comment: https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/data-sources/recursive-references-in-avro-schema-are-not-allowed

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe you should take a step back and rethink your solution.

You are trying to model relationships between friends, probably the best way to work with this would be using Graphs.

Try reading this:
https://databricks.com/blog/2016/03/03/introducing-graphframes.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible. What you are trying to do is a schema with infinite subschemas.

It can be done with a recursive function:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def friendSchema(n):
    if n == 0:
        return StructType([ \
            StructField("firstname", StringType(), True), \
            StructField("middlename", StringType(), True)])
    else:
        return StructType([ \
            StructField("firstname", StringType(), True), \
            StructField("middlename", StringType(), True), \
            StructField("friends", friendSchema(n - 1))])
```

Comment: In type systems, you can define types recursively. I can accept that Spark doesn't support it yet but it is not an unimaginable idea. The recursive implementation you provided, is not what I'm looking for (although I can see that there might be no choice).

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible,

but you can implement it by another approach.
by storing the data as JSON.
and reading it as a virtual table.
I know that will cost on the amount of i/o
but after this step, you create a table from the select of the virtual table.

- convert the data as JSON (with your recursion).
- store it on a temporary table.
- create a table from select on your temporary table.